# Find all lines in a file that are prefixes of any of the lines in another

Tags: grep

Is there a way to find get all the lines in a file that are prefixes of any of the lines in another?

Using `grep` I can check if a single pattern is a prefix of any of the lines. For instance if `file1` is

```
1
2
3
```

and `file2` is

```
100
10
25
55
```

`grep '^1' file2` will give me

```
100
10
```

Is there a way to loop through the lines in `file1` and check if those lines are prefixes of the lines in `file2`? In this case if I check for prefixes from `file1` in `file2` the output will be

```
100
10
25
```

Comment: similar question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/497217/4667

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turn your `file1` into a list of proper regular expressions:

```
sed 's/^/^/' file1 >patterns
```

This simply inserts a `^` as the first character on each line.

Then use that with `grep` on your other file:

```
grep -f patterns file2
```

Testing:

```
$ sed 's/^/^/' file1 >patterns
$ cat patterns
^1
^2
^3
```

```
$ grep -f patterns file2
100
10
25
```

---

Without a temporary pattern file:

With a shell that understands process substitutions:

```
grep -f <( sed 's/^/^/' file1 ) file2
```

In a shell that don't have process substitutions:

```
sed 's/^/^/' file1 | grep -f /dev/stdin file2
```

With the process redirection facility of the `yash` shell (which uses the same *syntax* as the above process substitution, but with different semantics):

```
grep -f /dev/stdin file2 <( sed 's/^/^/' file1 )
```

Comment: Works really well. Although for large files it is really slow (as expected). Are there any faster alternatives? Perhaps something that can be applied after sorting the files?

Comment: @Unni I would rather question if this is the right way of solving whatever underlying issue that you are dealing with.  There may be better ways of doing it, depending on what it is that you're actually doing.  Note also that if you have patterns that are sub-patterns of each other, such as `^11` and `^1`, then the longer pattern can be removed.

Comment: @Unni How big is your pattern file (`file1`)?

Comment: The file contains more than 1.7M patterns and I am looking them up against 4.5M strings.

Comment: Use this approach on the patterns file *itself* to see whether any of the patterns are in fact prefixes of other patterns.  :)